# Adjustments on clip don't seem to take effect in multicam in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

I have a multicam project in Adobe Premire CC. Unfortunately, one of the source clips used was from a different model of camera from the other two, so I need to make some adjustments to make it match the other two. It needs to be colour corrected a bit, and deinterlaced.

By pressing CTRL and double clicking on the multicam clip in the timeline, it opens up a timeline where the 3 cameras are in separate tracks. I then tried making adjustments the problematic camera clip. However, when I switch back to the timeline that has the multicam clip, all my adjustments don't seem to have taken effect. It looks like the original settings for that camera's clip.

**How do I single out and edit one of the clips used in a multicam edit so that any adjustments will apply when viewed in the multicam view?**